# How to update React-Select state/ selected value via another input?

Tags: reactjs, react-select

I'm learning react and trying to update the state/selected value of a react-select drop down via a button. When the button is clicked, buttonClick() function is called to set the new state value but react-select state didn't change. Selected label in the drop down stayed the same. How do I change the state of react-select so that it display the new selected value? Thanks.

https://codesandbox.io/s/react-select-test-nv8d8

Answer (score 6, accepted):

react-select expects the selection `value` object to be one of the options passed as `options`

[image: Edit react-select-test (forked)]

so you need to keep track of selected value in a state and pass it to the component

Also check the logic in button click to get the option and set it.

```js
import React, { Component } from "react";
import Select from "react-select";
import axios from "axios";

export default class App extends Component {
  constructor(props) {
    super(props);
    this.state = {
      selectedValue: {},
      selectOptions: []
    };
  }

  async getOptions() {
    const res = await axios.get("https://jsonplaceholder.typicode.com/users");
    const data = res.data;

    const options = data.map((d) => ({
      value: d.id,
      label: d.name
    }));

    this.setState({ selectOptions: options });
  }

  handleChange(e) {
    console.log(e);
    this.setState({ selectedValue: e });
  }

  componentDidMount() {
    this.getOptions();
  }

  buttonClick = () => {
    const valueToSet = this.state.selectOptions.find((row) => {
      return row.value === 2 && row.label === "Ervin Howell";
    });

    if (valueToSet) {
      this.handleChange(valueToSet);
    }
  };

  render() {
    const { selectedValue = {} } = this.state;
    console.log(this.state.selectOptions);
    return (
      <div>
        <Select
          value={selectedValue}
          options={this.state.selectOptions}
          onChange={this.handleChange.bind(this)}
        />
        <p>
          You have selected <strong>{selectedValue.label}</strong> whose id is{" "}
          <strong>{selectedValue.value}</strong>
        </p>
        <button onClick={this.buttonClick}>Click</button>
      </div>
    );
  }
}
```

Answer (score 3):

Actually `handleChange`s `e` parameter is the selected options's event not the object that you want to send it in `buttonClick`s event:

```
  handleChange(e) {//e is the event not the object!
    console.log(e);
    this.setState({ id: e.value, name: e.label });
  }

  buttonClick = () => {        
    this.handleChange({ value: 2, label: "Ervin Howell" });// you can't pass object as the parameter
  };
```

Also for the selected value on the button click you can do this:

```
<Select
      value={{ id: this.state.id, label: this.state.name }}
      options={this.state.selectOptions}
      onChange={this.handleChange.bind(this)}
    />
```

[image: Edit react-select-test (forked)]

Comment: this does not set the selected value on the dropdown

Comment: @PrakashS I didn't understand that OP wants to updated `select` value on button click. Thank you for mention it. I Updated the code.